# PowerShell script to replace commas within double quotes with nothing

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a comma separated CSV file, where I intend to replace the commas in double quotes to nothing and also replace double quotes with nothing:

<sup>**Editor's note**: The *original* form of this question asked to "change [the] delimiter to pipe" (`|`), which is no longer a requirement; gms0ulman's answer was written when it still was.</sup>

```
$inform = Get-Content C:\test.csv
$inform | % { 
$info = $_.ToString().Replace(",","") 
$var = $info 
$var | Out-file C:\test1.csv -Append 
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

In:

```
1,2,"Test,ABC"
```

Out:

```
1,2,TestABC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want (tested in PSv5.1):

```
Import-Csv C:\test.csv | ForEach-Object -Begin { $writeHeader = $True } {
  if ($writeHeader) { $writeHeader = $False; $_.psobject.properties.Name -join ',' }
  $_.psobject.properties.Value -replace ',', '' -join ','
} | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 test1.csv
```

- `Import-Csv` reads your CSV file into custom objects (`[pscustomobject]` instances) whose properties contain the column values with double quotes removed.

  - Since the column values are then stored in distinct properties, column-*internal* `,` instances can therefore blindly replaced without worrying about column-*separating* `,` instances.
  - That the enclosing double quotes were automatically stripped is a beneficial side effect, though care must be taken not to reintroduce them on output - read on.
- The problem is that you can *not* use `Export-Csv` after modifying the objects, because it *invariably adds double quotes* (back) around all output values.
- Therefore, a custom mini-script must be executed for each custom object, using `ForEach-Object`:

  - `-Begin { $writeHeader = $True }` is executed once at the beginning to signal the need to output a header row before the first data row.
  - `$_.psobject.properties` is the collection of all properties defined on the input object, named for the header columns, and containing a given data row's values.
  - `$_.psobject.properties.Name -join ','` outputs the header row, simply by joining the property names - which are the column headers - with `,` to yield a single output string.
  - `$_.psobject.properties.Value -replace ',', ''` removes any value-internal `,` instances (replaces them with the empty string), and `-join ','` again joins the resulting values as-is with `,`, outputting a data row.
- `Set-Content` - which is preferable to `Out-File` here, because the output objects are already *strings* - is used to write to the output file.

  - Note the `-Encoding` parameter to control the output character encoding -adjust as needed.
  - In *Windows PowerShell* (versions up to v5.1), not using `-Encoding` would default to your system's "ANSI" code page (even though the help topic claims ASCII), whereas `Out-File` would default to UTF-16LE ("Unicode").

Answer (score 4):

Import the CSV.  Convert it to a CSV with a different delimiter.  Replace the commas.  Convert the delimiter back.  Replace the double quotes.  Write out the resulting file.

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\MyFile.csv |
    ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter '|' | 
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ',',[String]::Empty } | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|' | 
    ConvertTo-Csv |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace -replace '"',[String]::Empty } |
    Set-Content -Path C:\MyFile_fixed.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

I would break this down into two steps. Another StackOverflow user may be able to give you a  one-liner.

```
Import-Csv C:\test.csv | Export-Csv tempfile.csv -Delimiter "|"
(Get-Content tempfile.csv).Replace(",","").Replace('"',"") | Out-File test1.csv
```

Comment: @mklement0 I believe that's required, but OP had already done that part in code. The original question specified that the delimiter is changed from `,` to `|`... I'm leaving it in there as I think it's better to do in one go as oppose to iterate through the file as OP has.

Comment: I see; whatever the ultimate intent, ++ for a clever approach (it will be slow due to reading and writing the file twice, but whether that matters will depend on the use case). Unless you're worried about PSv2 compatibility, you can speed things up with `Get-Content -Raw`; conversely, if the file is too large to fit into memory at once, perform the `.Replace` calls in a `ForEach` call.
Even better, you can avoid the intermediate file  if you use `ConvertTo-Csv -NotypeInformation`, as in Bacon Bits' answer.

Answer (score 2):

Does your csv have headers? Are the values to be changed in the same column?

If it looks something like this :

```
h1,h2,h3
1,2,"Test,ABC"
3,4,"Test,DEF"
```

This should work:

```
$Csv = Import-Csv -path C:\MyFile.csv
$Csv.H3 | foreach {$_.Replace('"',"").Replace(",","")}
```

Edit:
Made it work. But basically the same as  mklement0's solution

```
$Csv = Import-Csv -path C:\MyFile.csv
$Csv | Foreach {$_.H3 = $_.H3.Replace(",","")}
$CsvObject = $Csv | Convertto-Csv -NoTypeInformation
$CsvObject.replace('"','') | 
Set-Content C:\OutFile.Csv
```

Comment: ++; maybe you just did it for readability, but note that using intermediate variables that collect all results _in memory_ is problematic with large files. You can just use a single pipeline instead, which processes objects one at a time. Quibble: `$CsvObject` is an unfortunate variable name, given that it contains an _array of strings_ (lines).

Comment: Good points. My approach to this problem would be to try and fix the formatting problem before I created the csv file but that might be limited by the data source. There seems to be an over reliance sometimes on txt files, csv files etc. It might be a hangover from cmd. Interesting that Import-Csv produces an object but Convertto-Csv produces strings seems counter-intuitive at first glance.