# PowerShell script bigger KB file then if I open the file and save it

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

PowerShell script produces a 275KB csv file that will not run in a program we use here but if I open the file and do nothing to it but save it, it will save around 238KB and the program runs fine at the point is there a way I can run a program to open the file and save it after the script runs each night or has maybe there is a way to export csv file that won't cause the difference. here is my script below

```bsh
$OUs = "OU=Windows 10 Users,OU=XXX Users,DC=XXXXXXXX,DC=XXXXXXXXX,DC=com","OU=Domain Users,OU=XXX Users,DC=XXXXXXX,DC=XXXXXx,DC=com"

$result = 
foreach($OU in $OUs){

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OU -Properties UseraccountControl, displayName, sAMAccountName, extensionAttribute1, extensionAttribute3, mail |
where {$_.UseraccountControl -notlike “*accountdisabled*”} |
Select-Object displayName, sAMAccountName, extensionAttribute1, extensionAttribute3, mail}

$result |Export-Csv C:\Temp\test2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Are you using PowerShell Core (v6+) (default to BOM-less UTF-8) or Windows PowerShell (`Export-Csv` defaults to ASCII)? What editor are you using to re-save the file? What changes in the file when you re-save? Character encoding? Newlines (CRLF vs. LF)? Both? Please add clarifications directly to your question, don't respond in a comment.

Comment: i am running major 5 minor 1 build 19041 revision 1. default is  utf8NoBOM but did try ascii and utf7 and others same thing. I am making no changes to the file just double click the file and it opens in excel and click the save icon then close the file and it drops to 238KB

Comment: Note that opening a CSV file in Excel and re-saving it can result in inadvertent modification of the data. The drop in file size is most likely due to Excel stripping double quotes (`"`) from around the column values, which `Export-Csv` _invariably_ adds by default; in PowerShell [Core], you can now use `-UseQuotes AsNeeded` to only use double quotes when necessary. In Windows PowerShell (versions up to v5.1, as in your case), you'll have to use something other than `Export-Csv` - see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44828498/45375).

Comment: P.S.: `utf8NoBOM` as an `-Encoding` value / BOM-less UTF-8 in general are _not_ available in Windows PowerShell (versions up to v5.1), at least via _cmdlets_.